# ngx-codemirror - Unable to use fold gutter in XML Message

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, codemirror

I have an Angular application and I'm using `ngx-codemirror` to build a codemirror in my respective application. In ngx-codemirror there's an option called `foldgutter` and I have made it true.

**app.component.ts**

```
  public codeMirrorOptions: any = {
    theme: 'material',
    lineNumbers: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    foldGutter: true,
    gutters: ["CodeMirror-linenumbers", "CodeMirror-foldgutter", "CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
    autoCloseBrackets: true,
    matchBrackets: true
  };
```

**app.component.html**

```
  <ngx-codemirror [(ngModel)]="selectedMessageBody"
                                        [options]="codeMirrorOptions">
                        </ngx-codemirror>
```

By setting up the respective value, I'm able to use fold gutter if the message is JSON but if it's XML the folder gutter option is not visible.

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

STACKBLITZ DEMO => https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-codemirror-dmo9cy

And also is there any other package available to resolve this issue?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I'm able to use fold gutter in JSON message but it's not showing in XML message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed importing the below two

```
import 'codemirror/mode/xml/xml';
import 'codemirror/addon/fold/xml-fold';
```

and also you need to set the `mode:xml` under `codeMirrorOptions`. Usually what people mistake is use `application/xml` which was the case with my friend as well :)

Happy coding

Comment: I think you are fast, i was trying to create a demo for the same

Comment: @Sajeetharan its just pure luck :D

Answer (score 3):

You need to add in your module

```
import 'codemirror/mode/xml/xml';
import 'codemirror/addon/fold/xml-fold';
```

and change the app.component options as

```
<ngx-codemirror #codemirrorr
   [options]="{
    lineNumbers: true,
    theme: 'idea',
    mode: 'application/xml',
     gutters: ['CodeMirror-linenumbers', 'CodeMirror-foldgutter', 'CodeMirror-lint-markers'],
    foldGutter: true,
     autoCloseBrackets: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    lint: true
  }"
  [(ngModel)]="xmlString"
  (ngModelChange)="setEditorContent($event)">
</ngx-codemirror>
```

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-codemirror-5rrrjs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sajeetharan. :)

Comment: Hi Folks , does this code folding works for gherkin mode ?